# Access members of inner class from the outer class - TypeScript

Tags: class, typescript, namespaces, inner-classes

I'm trying to group some members of a class in TypeScript. Consider the following class:

```
export class MyClass {

  private member: string = 'foo';

  public getFoo(): string {

    this._doSomething();

    return this.member;

  }

  // Helper
  _doSomething() { console.log(this.member); }

}
```

What I basically want to do is to wrap `_doSomething` with a namespace (let's call the namespace `helpers`) so inside `getFoo()` I can call `this.helpers._doSomething()`.

Of course, this is super easy to do in Javascript since we can define an object as a member and define the helper functions inside the object.

In TypeScript, I almost got the same effect through class expressions:

```
export class MyClass {

  private member: string = 'foo';

  public getFoo(): string {

    this.helpers._doSomething();

    return this.member;

  }

  private helpers = class {

    // To have access to the parent's members
    constructor(private parent: MyClass) { }

    public _doSomething() { console.log(this.parent.member); }

  };

}
```

The only problem is that the `MyClass` can't have access to `helpers` class members.

How do I get access to the inner class members from the outer class?

Is there a better way to achieve the namespace `helpers`?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### Updated

Using the accepted answer achieves the goal:

```
export class MyClass {

  private member: string = 'foo';

  public getFoo(): string {

    this.helpers._doSomething();

    return this.member;

  }

  private helpers = new (class {

    // To have access to the parent's members
    constructor(private parent: MyClass) { }

    public _doSomething() { console.log(this.parent.member); }

  })(this);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just defined the class, to have access to the non-static members you have to new it up. You can do this inline like so :

```
export class MyClass {

  private member: string = 'foo';

  public getFoo(): string {

    this.helpers._doSomething();

    return this.member;

  }

  private helpers = new (class {

    // To have access to the parent's members
    constructor(private parent: MyClass) { }

    public _doSomething() { console.log(this.parent.member); }

  })(this);

}
```

Or if you want to have multiple instances of the helper class you can new it up as needed:

```
public getFoo(): string {

  let h = new this.helpers(this);
  let h1 = new this.helpers(this);
  h._doSomething();
  h1._doSomething();
  return this.member;

}
```

You can achieve a similar effect by using the merging of a class and a namespace, the problem is you will not have access to private members, while your solution requires this:

```
export class MyClass {
  // Must be public for access from helper
  public member: string = 'foo';

  public getFoo(): string {
    let h = new MyClass.helpers(this);
    h._doSomething();
    return this.member;
  }
}

export namespace MyClass {
  // must be exported to be accesible from the class
  export class helpers {
    // To have access to the parent's members
    constructor(private parent: MyClass) { }
    public _doSomething() { console.log(this.parent.member); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops! It totally hit me when my constructor didn't execute! Thanks for the answer (I'll accept it in 8 minutes!). Is there a better way to get the namespace effect? It would be really good if I could just define a namespace inside the class and wrap my helpers with it...

Comment: Nope you can't create a namespace within a class. If you want the class to be contained within your class, this looks to be the best option. Another option would be to just declare it in the same file, as long as you don't export the helper class it will only be visible inside that file which might be good enough.

Comment: @RamtinSoltani Added a solution using namespace and class emrging, but your's works better because you don't have to expose the helper and private fields.

Comment: That's also good to know. But it requires the member to be public which might be a problem (though the member won't actually be private since Javascript doesn't support private object properties!)